# How can I use the random function with variables that are words?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I'm creating a project where the person is supposed to respond and this randomizer is supposed to send a random response that would either be in the category of yes and no.

Comment: Put the words in a list, then pick a random element of the list with `random.choice()`.

Comment: @Barmar I did what you told me to do but then I got this error message:      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project3.py", line 12, in <module>
    from classref3 import Dog
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Documents/itt/independent_projects/classref3.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Dog:
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Documents/itt/independent_projects/classref3.py", line 43, in Dog
    import random
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Documents/itt/independent_projects/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    integers

Comment: @DawnChopin Don't name your _own_ file as random.py because that will hide the _true_ random module.

Comment: I reverted back to the original question. **If you have a new question, ask a new, separate question**. When you [completely changed the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58278961/2), the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279062/2745495) and the comments do not all make sense anymore. Also, the original post was already closed and marked as a duplicate, making it unlikely someone else will notice it. Ask a new question if you have new problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` to select a random element from a list of strings.

```
import random

allResponses = ['yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'so']
randomResponse = random.choice(responses)
```

See `random.choice` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: Is this for python 2.7?

Comment: @DawnChopin yes

Comment: File "classref3.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Dog:
  File "classref3.py", line 43, in Dog
    import random
  File "/Users/sergioley-languren/Documents/itt/independent_projects/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    integers
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
This the Error I got from this

Comment: @DawnChopin Don't name your _own_ file as random.py because that will hide the _true_ random module.